# Join two queries (partially completed already)

Tags: sql-server, join, case

I am attempting to join the two queries together. The two queries function properly separately. I've gotten the CASE statement from query 2 to work with query 1.

Some background, this query is being run against a business intelligence program that creates graphs/charts off autorun inserts. Right now when no new data is inserted into the table for a specific IM.NAME the program looks back to the last record, which skews the chart results. I need a '1' to print out when one of the 5 IM.NAME fields does not return based on the master query below. I've included a SQLfiddle showing the 2nd query in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2cdbd/1

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
SA.DELETED,
PAT.VERSION, 
PAT.PATTERNDATE,
SA.AGENT_VERSION,
SCL.COMPUTER_NAME AS Computer_Name,
SCO.OPERATION_SYSTEM AS Operation_System,
dateadd(s,convert(bigint,SA.CREATION_TIME)/1000,
'01-01-1970 00:00:00') CREATION_DTTM,
dateadd(s,convert(bigint,SA.LAST_UPDATE_TIME)/1000,
'01-01-1970  00:00:00')  Lastupdatetime,
DATEADD(s, convert(bigint,LAST_SCAN_TIME)/1000,
'01-01-1970 00:00:00')LAST_SCAN_TIME,
PAT.PATTERNDATE AS Pattern_Date,
SCL.USER_NAME AS User_Name,
VSC.IP_ADDR1_TEXT AS IP_Add,
CASE WHEN IM.NAME LIKE  '%-FRN%' THEN IM.NAME
WHEN IM.NAME LIKE '%-BCK%' THEN IM.NAME
WHEN IM.NAME LIKE  '%-PPP%' THEN IM.NAME
WHEN IM.NAME LIKE '%-MES%' THEN IM.NAME
WHEN IM.NAME LIKE  '%-MMT%' THEN IM.NAME
 ELSE '1' END AS Group_Name,
 IM.NAME as test


FROM ((((SEM_AGENT SA

INNER JOIN SEM_CLIENT SCL
ON ((SA.COMPUTER_ID=SCL.COMPUTER_ID) 
AND (SA.DOMAIN_ID=SCL.DOMAIN_ID)) 
AND (SA.GROUP_ID=SCL.GROUP_ID)) 

INNER JOIN SEM_COMPUTER   SCO
ON ((SA.COMPUTER_ID=SCO.COMPUTER_ID) 
AND (SA.DOMAIN_ID=SCO.DOMAIN_ID)) 
AND (SA.DELETED=SCO.DELETED))

INNER JOIN PATTERN PAT 
ON SA.PATTERN_IDX=PAT.PATTERN_IDX) 
INNER JOIN IDENTITY_MAP IM 
ON SCL.GROUP_ID=IM.ID) 

INNER JOIN V_SEM_COMPUTER VSC 
ON SCO.COMPUTER_ID=VSC.COMPUTER_ID 
AND SA.DELETED=0


WHERE PAT.Patterndate < (SELECT MAX(Patterndate) -1 FROM Pattern)
AND SCO.OPERATION_SYSTEM NOT LIKE '%2000%'
ORDER BY Computer_Name





Select (CASE WHEN IM.NAME LIKE  '%-FRN%' THEN IM.NAME
  WHEN IM.NAME LIKE '%-BCK%' THEN IM.NAME
  WHEN IM.NAME LIKE  '%-PPP%' THEN IM.NAME
  WHEN IM.NAME LIKE '%-MES%' THEN IM.NAME
  WHEN IM.NAME LIKE  '%-MMT%' THEN IM.NAME
  ELSE '1' END) AS Group_Name,
   tagTypes.tagType,
   IM.NAME 

From
(
Select '%-FRN%' AS tagType
UNION
Select '%-BCK%' AS tagType
UNION
Select '%-PPP%' AS tagType
UNION
Select '%-MES%' AS tagType
UNION
Select '%-MMT%' AS tagType
)     AS tagTypes
left join
IDENTITY_MAP IM 
    on IM.NAME like tagTypes.tagType
```